# Getting Access violation writing location 0x00000014 with fprintf

Tags: c++, c, access-violation, printf

I'm working on Visual studio 2010. The program itself is originally designed thinking to a future port for CUDA, so all is set to go to it, but for now I'm just testing if it works on plain c++ (actually I'm trying to stick to c for now, since I'm more familiar with it).

The relevant code is:

```
#define NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES 21
#define NMBR_Ls 3
#define NMBR_POINTS 20000

<Emin, Emax, dE are initialized as global constants>
int NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES_L[NMBR_Ls];

<Some functions>

void write_results(double ** u, int * NmbrNodes, int * div){
const char prefix[] = "wave_function_";
char filename[24];
double *eigenergies;
int div0,i,j,k,l,m;
FILE *file_u;
FILE *file_output;

eigenergies = (double *)malloc(NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES*sizeof(double));
j=0;
m=0;
file_output = fopen("computation_results.out","w");
fprintf(file_output,"This file contains  the output\n");


for(l=0;l<NMBR_Ls;l++){
    div0=div[l*NMBR_ENERGIES];
    for(i = l*NMBR_ENERGIES;i<NMBR_ENERGIES*(l+1);i++){
        if (div[i] != div0 && m<NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES_L[l]){
            div0=div[i];
            j++;
            m++;
            eigenergies[j-1] = (Emin+((double) (i-l*NMBR_ENERGIES))*dE)-dE/2.0;
            fprintf(file_output,"The eigenergy %d is %1.15lf and the wavefunction has %d nodes\n",j,eigenergies[j-1],NmbrNodes[i]);
            sprintf(filename,"%d_%s%d.out",l,prefix,j);
            file_u = fopen(filename,"w");
            for(k=0;k<NMBR_POINTS;k++){
                fprintf(file_u,"%lf %1.15lf \n",k*RMAX/NMBR_POINTS,u[i][k]);
            }
            fclose(file_u);
        }
    }
    if (j < NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES_L[l]){
        j = NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES_L[l];
    }
    m=0;
    }
fprintf(file_output,"R = %1.15lf\n ",error_control(eigenergies));
fprintf(file_output,"%d eigenergies were found\nIts eigenfunctions were stored on the file %sj.out, 1<j<%d",j,prefix,j);
fclose(file_output);
free(eigenergies);
}

<Some functions>

int main(void){

<Code that executes the computation and stores it on u[i][j],NmbrNodes[i] and div[i]>

write_results(u, NmbrNodes, div);

}
```

The vector div was previously filled with 1 and -1 as needed. The program runs fine while l = 0 and l =1. However when he starts the outer loop for the last time (l = 2) and it enters the if for the second time, it crashes on the line `fprintf(file_output,"The eigenergy %d is %1.15lf and the wavefunction has %d nodes\n",j,eigenergies[j-1],NmbrNodes[i]);`. The error message is

```
First-chance exception at 0x77dd3ea0 in Potential_Model_Numerov.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
Unhandled exception at 0x77dd3ea0 in Potential_Model_Numerov.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

When choosing to break the program, it opens the mlock.c file at the end of the function `void __cdecl _lock`.

I have already checked I'm not reading any of the vectors beyond their allocated space (eigenergies goes until eigenergies[20] and j =17 when this happens as well NmbrNodes goes until NmbrNodes[3071] and i = 3009 on the moment of the crash). So I don't know why he is trying to read a forbbiden memory address. Does any one have any idea?

Thanks!

Side notes: I have another function which does basically the same thing, but without writting anything to the hard drive, and this one runs just fine. Also, sometimes it opens the file osfinfo.c instead of mlock.c and stops at the end of the function `int __cdecl __lock_fhandle`.

Comment: If you break the fprintf into separate statements for each thing you're printing you'll see which memory reference is causing the problem. print these separately `eigenergies[j-1]` and `NmbrNodes[i]`

Comment: You don't check that `file_output` was opened successfully. If it does fail to open, your program enters UB. Depending on the configuration and optimization settings, it might not crash immediately.

Comment: I implemented the suggestion of breaking my printf in several parts. The error happens in the `fprintf(file_output,"The eigenergy %d",j);`. However my debugger can access it and show me it is storing the value 17. It could be what nneonneo said. I asked it to check if file_output == 0 to see if it was properly initialized and it was. I know it is not the best solution, so I'm trying to figure out how to open and write things using c++ commands instead of c to be able to use is_open() to make the test.

Comment: Do you end up with `InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount` or `EnterCriticalSection` on the stack?

Comment: @joshpoley I'm not sure what do you mean. Is these some kind of error? (Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a newbie to c++). If it is, there was not such error message on my output windows. Or should I be looking on a different place for these errors messages?

Comment: What is the full stack? I'm looking at the source for `_lock` and `__lock_fhandle` and the most likely spots for a write AV would be in a call into the OS' critical section APIs.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? (That is -- something we can compile without toying in reading your mind about what were your values for NMBR_ENERGIES, Emin, etc.)

Comment: I finally solved my problem by rewritting the entire function (Actually I just copied paste the function I mentioned previously that did the computation without writting to the file and added the printf's). I don't know where the problem is though, since for me the code seens identical. If anyone feels curious and wants to look on both functions to see what I mean, you can see it here http://bit.ly/19HuLNL. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `eigenenergies` is not `NULL`? You never check the return value of `malloc()`.

Given that you get an access violation is at address 0x00000014 and you claim that

> eigenergies goes until eigenergies[20]

that would be my first guess. Note that `0x14` equals `20`.

You might want to skip `malloc()`ing and just use `double eigenenergies[NMBR_EXP_ENERGIES]`.